# Repeat rows of an array N times depending on the length of my df in a for loop is not working. Error 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable" (Python)

Tags: python, loops, numpy

Ok so, I have looked for other similar questions but I just can't get it to work. 
1) I have a for-loop that reads multiple files 
2) For each file I need its lenght (T)
3) Then I need the values of the df repeated (T) times.

This works fine if I'm not using a for loop, however by using the same script in a loop the error I get is 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable. Which I believe is because I'm treating the np.repeat as a function but I'm not sure how to fix it. Any good advice on how to fix this?

```
result_files = '/Users/result_files' 
reservoirs = ['AA','AB', etc.]

for res in reservoirs:
    res_files = pd.read_csv('{}/{}_storage.csv'.format(result_files,res), index_col=0, skiprows=1, parse_dates=True)

    T = len(res_files)

    ### Df of number of days per month x length of reservoir's data 
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df, orient='index')
    df = df.transpose()   
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(df.values,T,axis=0))
```

Error

```
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 974, in from_dict
    if isinstance(list(data.values())[0], (Series, dict)):

TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

For example,  lets say my df has these values:

```
df= ( 1.3, 1.5, 1.7)
```

And my file has a lenght of 3, my output should look like this

```
T = 3


[Out]
df= ( 1.3, 1.5, 1.7
      1.3, 1.5, 1.7
      1.3, 1.5, 1.7. )
```

Comment: Whenever you report a Python error, include the *complete* traceback (i.e. the complete error message) in the question.  There is useful information in there.

Comment: *"Which I believe is because I'm treating the np.repeat as a function ..."*  `np.repeat` *is* a function, so that should not cause the error.  It would be easier for someone to help you if you provided a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Check this line: `df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df, orient='index')`.  You are overwriting the original value of `df` with a Pandas DataFrame.  You don't show how `df` is originally created, but after the first time this line is executed, `df` is a DataFrame, not a dict.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I've edited my question, to show more info. I don't mind to overwrite it since I need the same data for T times in every loop. @WarrenWeckesser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 974, in from_dict
    if isinstance(list(data.values())[0], (Series, dict)):

TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

If `data` is a dataframe, it would produce this error, because `value` is an array, not a function.  See the DF docs:

```
DataFrame.values
Return a Numpy representation of the DataFrame.
```

What `from_dict` expects is a dictionary, which does have a `values` method.

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df, orient='index')
```

So your code would work on the first iteration if `df` is created as a dictionary, but fail on the next loop when `df` is a dataframe (from the end of the last loop).